# Why is my computer really slow 20% of the times I turn it on?

Tags: windows-7, performance, vlc-media-player

The problem is that 1 out of 5 times when I turn my computer on, it turns into this sort of "mode" where whenever I open a window, it does it really slow and whenever I close a window, that too is done really slow. Operating within the window isn't particularly slow but whenever I try to watch something on Windows Media Player, it also is played in slow motion. Using VLC makes the movie sort of, twitchy.

Turning it off and on again usually works, this just feels like a very strange thing for a computer to do and when I'm in a hurry and just have to check or fix something it does get infuriating. What is wrong with my computer and what can I try doing to fix it?

Comment: Try opening the Performance Monitor to see what's going on

Comment: Or xperf, which is like the swiss army knife of performance problems

Comment: Seems like a graphics driver that's draining your resources. Try to update your drivers and see if it solves the problem.

Answer (score -3):

Stop Unnecessary Background Programs:-

Sometimes there are some background programs that are running without our consent and eating up the memory and energy of the CPU. Closing down these programs will speed up your laptop performance. To do so follow the instructions below:

- Hold Windows+R button on your keyboard
- Type msconfig and press Enter
- Click on Startup tab
- Click on Disable All
- Restart your Computer

If it doesn't helps you then try to defrag the registry. I always defrag the registry with Reginout. Thanks